# ASP.Net MVC Membership issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using WebSecurity in my c# MVC web application but I'm having some problems.

I have initialized it in Bootstrapper.cs:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "Users", "UserId", "Email", true);
```

I know that once you call `WebSecurity.Login()` that you have to wait a full page load before checking whether the user is logged in, however when that returns true, I am redirecting to the home page. Then if I click on the Login link in my application again, it thinks my user is not logged in.

Any ideas why this happens?

Here is my controller:

```
using Football_League.Models.User;
using Football_League.Models.View;
using Football_League.Services.User;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Football_League.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : BaseController
    {
        // GET: Account/Register
        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            if(this.isLoggedIn()) return RedirectHome();
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Account/RegisterPost
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Register(RegisterView model, string Password, string ConfirmPassword)
        {
            if (this.isLoggedIn()) return RedirectHome();

            // Validate Input
            if(!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View();
            }

            if(this.authentication.Register(model.Email, model.Password, model.ExtraParams()))
            {
                ViewData["flash-type"] = "success";
                ViewData["flash-message"] = "Account created successfully. You may now Login.";
            }
            else
            {
                ViewData["flash-type"] = "danger";
                ViewData["flash-message"] = "Account creation failed.";
            }

            return View();
        }

        // GET: Account/Login
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            if (this.isLoggedIn()) return RedirectHome();
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Account/Login
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginView model)
        {
            if (this.isLoggedIn()) return RedirectHome();

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }

            if(this.authentication.Login(model.Email, model.Password))
            {
                return RedirectHome();
            }

            ViewData["flash-type"] = "danger";
            ViewData["flash-message"] = "Could not log you in, are your details correct?";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Logout()
        {
            if (this.isLoggedIn()) this.authentication.Logout();
            return RedirectHome();
        }
    }
}
```

and the class controlling my Authentication:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using WebMatrix.WebData;

namespace Football_League.Authentication
{
    public class BaseAuthentication : Football_League.Authentication.Authentication
    {
        public bool Login(string email, string password)
        {
            var success = WebSecurity.Login(email, password, false);
            return success;
        }

        public void Logout()
        {
            WebSecurity.Logout();
        }

        public bool isLoggedIn()
        {
            return WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated;
        }

        public bool Register(string username, string password, object user)
        {
            try
            {
                WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(username, password, user);
            }
            catch(MembershipCreateUserException e)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:** As requested, here is my **BaseController** class that is the parent for all Controllers (which contains the `RedirectHome()` method):

```
using Football_League.Authentication;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Football_League.Controllers
{
    public abstract class BaseController : Controller
    {
        public Authentication.Authentication authentication
        {
            get { return AuthenticationFactory.resolve(); }
        }

        protected bool isLoggedIn()
        {
            return this.authentication.isLoggedIn();
        }

        protected bool isGuest()
        {
            return !this.isLoggedIn();
        }

        protected bool isAdmin()
        {
            // TODO: isAdmin method.
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        protected ActionResult RedirectHome()
        {
            return Redirect("/");
        }
    }
}
```